# Docker image build failed with "COPY failed: no source files were specified"

Tags: docker, go

I'm trying to build a docker image using Golang Docker SDK but its failing with `{"message": "COPY failed: no source files were specified"}," error": "COPY failed: no source files were specified"}`

here is my code

```
 package main
 import (
  "archive/tar"
  "bytes"
  "context"
  "fmt"
  "io"
  "io/ioutil"
  "os"

  "github.com/docker/docker/api/types"
  "github.com/docker/docker/client"
 )

func buildImage(client *client.Client, tags []string, dockerfile string) error {
ctx := context.Background()

// Create a buffer
buf := new(bytes.Buffer)
tw := tar.NewWriter(buf)
defer tw.Close()

// Create a filereader
dockerFileReader, err := os.Open(dockerfile)
if err != nil {
    return err
}

// Read the actual Dockerfile
readDockerFile, err := ioutil.ReadAll(dockerFileReader)
if err != nil {
    return err
}

// Make a TAR header for the file
tarHeader := &tar.Header{
    Name: dockerfile,
    Size: int64(len(readDockerFile)),
}

// Writes the header described for the TAR file
err = tw.WriteHeader(tarHeader)
if err != nil {
    return err
}

// Writes the dockerfile data to the TAR file
_, err = tw.Write(readDockerFile)
if err != nil {
    return err
}

dockerFileTarReader := bytes.NewReader(buf.Bytes())

buildOptions := types.ImageBuildOptions{
    Context:    dockerFileTarReader, 
    Dockerfile: dockerfile,
    Remove:     true,
    Tags:       tags,
}
// Build the actual image
imageBuildResponse, err := client.ImageBuild(
    ctx,
    dockerFileTarReader,
    buildOptions,
)

if err != nil {
    return err
}

// Read the STDOUT from the build process
defer imageBuildResponse.Body.Close()
_, err = io.Copy(os.Stdout, imageBuildResponse.Body)
if err != nil {
    return err
}

return nil
}
```

Here is my folder structure, trying to build a docker image using the Dockerfile of src.
I want to consider all files inside `src` for the docker build.

```
-- root
   |-- src 
       |--Dockerfile
       |--files
   |-- go-code
       |--build.go
```

**Dockerfile**

```
FROM node:12


WORKDIR /app
COPY package*.json ./
RUN npm install

COPY . .

EXPOSE 3000

CMD [ "node", "index.js" ]
```

Detailed error message:

```
{"errorDetail":{"message":"COPY failed: no source files were specified"},"error":"COPY failed: no source files were specified"}
```

Comment: What's in the Dockerfile?  Separately from your program, does `docker build src` work?  Are you copying any of the `src/files/` into the tar file you're sending as the build context, or only the Dockerfile?

Comment: A little piece of me dies every time I see some SDK for building `docker` images. The error is explicit, the `COPY` from the context failed during the build.

Comment: @DavidMaze added docker file, and its working using `docker build src` command.

Comment: Are you copying the other files into the build context tarball, or only the `Dockerfile`?  (I don't obviously see in this code where you send Docker the `package.json` file.)

Answer (score 0):

This depends on where you're calling your docker build from.
For eg.

```
-- root
   |-- src 
       |--Dockerfile
       |--files
   |-- go-code
       |--build.go
```

In case you want to copy the files in `/root/src/files/`, you need to cd to the `/root/src` folder.
In that case, the docker command would be:
`docker built -t <tagname> .`

In your case, the first "." in the COPY command will try to copy from the directory where the build.go is running.

Which is probably why your script is failing.

Comment: I also tried to change the current dir to /root/src/files but still getting the same error. `os.Chdir("/root/src/files")`